# Jquery Replace br tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, text

I have text with several line break tags like so

```
<br></br>
```

and several double line breaks like so

```
<br></br><br></br>
```

I want to get rid of the single `<br></br>`, but I want to keep the double ones
Using jquery or Jscript how can I tell it to do this
When I used `.filter("<br></br>")` it did not work because it got rid of both

Is there a way to replace the instances of `<br></br><br></br>` with replaceWith? Or some other way

Comment: Can you show me an example of a result you want? You can replace all '<br></br>' into '<br />'. Is that what you want? You can use the javascript [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method though.

Comment: @RickHitchcock: Indeed. However, it is valid XHTML; and OP did not specify the doctype in the question. Still, the question is not about rendering, but text manipulation.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is the three-step process:

```
text = text.
  replace(/<br><\/br><br><\/br>/g, '____MAGICMARKER____').
  replace(/<br><\/br>/g, '').
  replace(/____MAGICMARKER____/g, '<br></br><br></br>')
```

hoping that `____MAGICMARKER____` is never, nor will ever, be a part of your text. Another possibility (and a better, foolproof one) would be:

```
text = text.replace(/(<br><\/br>)+/g, function(all, once) {
  if (all == once) return "";
  return all;
});
```

Note that this is all written assuming your premise in the question is correct: you have a text (i.e. a string). If you have a document fragment, then you want to do this operation on its `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `html` , `RegExp` `/<br><br>+[\s|\n]/g` to match `<br><br>` followed by space character or new line character

```js
$("body").html(function(i, html) {
  return html.replace(/<br><br>+[\s|\n]/g, "")
});

console.log($("body").html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<body>
<br></br>
and several double line breaks like so

<br></br><br></br>
<br></br>
and several double line breaks like so

<br></br><br></br>
<br></br>
and several double line breaks like so

<br></br><br></br>
</body>
```